# how to write nodejs ReadFile Line by Line in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm tring to write in **Typescript** this example from NodeJS API reference

my node version is **v12.16.0**

[Example: Read File Stream Line-by-Line](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html)

here the part I'm interested in:

```
const { once } = require('events');
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');
const { createInterface } = require('readline');

(async function processLineByLine() {
  try {
    const rl = createInterface({
      input: createReadStream('big-file.txt'),
      crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    rl.on('line', (line) => {
      // Process the line.
    });

    await once(rl, 'close');

    console.log('File processed.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

unfortunately I haven't find a way to handle the part

```
 await once(rl, 'close');
```

I have tried to `import { once } from 'events';` and `import * as events from 'events';`

Why do I need to import `once`?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting

Comment: if i  `import {once } from 'events;` i got  `Module '"events"' has no exported member 'once'`and if  `import * as events from 'events';` I got ` Property 'once' does not exist on type 'typeof internal'`

Comment: ensure you have installed @types/node.

Comment: I'm sure i have node types

Comment: Can you please tell us the node.js version installed on your machine?

Comment: Hi I edited the question anyway node version is v12.16.0